# wire-tap is not working with Spring Integration 4.2.5 RELEASE

Tags: spring-integration

Recently I migrated spring integration 4.1.6.RELEASE to 4.2.5 RELEASE but after this wire-tap is not working.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with 4.2.5 RELEASE?

Comment: Please describe "not working" in more details and show your configuration. We just fixed a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4020) for cases with multiple wire taps without an `id` attribute. It has a work-around - see the JIRA issue.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for the quick response, I have a multiple wire-taps in my test-context.xml, as you said if i provide an id attribute then it is working fine.

Comment: Please "accept" the answer (click the check/tick mark under the voting buttons on the left). It will help other users looking for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Spring Integration 4.2.6 resolves the problem with several global `<wire-tap>` without an `id`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4020.

The workaround for previous version is to specify an `id` for each of them.